# Log off to apply display changes

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, dpi

Why is it necessary to log off Windows 7 in order to apply certain display changes, in particular the 100% / 125% / 150% magnification options in the Display control panel?

Is there a way to do something equivalent, but without having to log off and back on again?